# Which is the correct option for passing args to class methods

Tags: python

Which would be the correct one?
Because I have some doubts :(

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = BAR()
    def get_foo(self, bar):
        return bar
    def foo_bar(self):
        bar = self.bar
        self.get_foo(bar)
```

or

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = BAR()
    def get_foo(self):
        bar = self.bar 
        return bar
    def foo_bar(self):
        bar = self.bar
        self.get_foo()
```

Of course, we assume bar will be used more than once in both methods.

Comment: You don't have any class methods?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do... neither of the examples make sense to me.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, I asked this because I just tried the both versions with a custom class and it seems to work.

Comment: The first `get_foo` will never return `self.bar`, I'm not even sure why you have this method in your class, its just returning whatever you are passing to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends of course. If it makes sense to call `get_foo` with a different `bar` than the one stored within the object, then of course you would want to accept it as a parameter. On the other hand, if you are only using `self.bar` for the value, then it makes no sense to accept it as a parameter requiring you to do essentially `self.get_foo(self.bar)` all the time.

If your `get_foo` really just returns `self.bar` though, you should think about getting rid of it completely. You could just access `self.bar` directly then.

Comment: ...or make it into a property.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid If there’s no logic behind it, you don’t need a property though.

Comment: It won't return just self.bar. My initial thought was to avoid having duplicate code. I use more than once self.bar and in each method I cache it. Therefore, instead of caching in two methods wouldn't be better to just pass the cached one as an argument to the second and avoid an extra line of code?

Comment: @jabez - [Explicit is better than implicit](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) and [readability counts](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

Comment: @jabez: update your question with a description of what exactly you're trying to do. because the codes don't make sense.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, you're right. Now it's clear :)

Comment: @jabez Caching a variable to save look ups would be micro-optimization and as such you should avoid doing that. It just makes the situation more complicated to read and your intention less clear. Focus on what you are doing instead; also, leave the public interface of your class clean, so a parameter for (uncessary) caching purposes would be very confusing to users.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, it's just a dummy example.

Comment: avoid writing code that has unnecessary side-effects, which by the way you are describing what you are doing - will.

Comment: @jabez: exactly. that's my problem.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, it was a matter of how to it in general. but I got my answer. thanks.